# Is there anyway to query SQLAlchemy using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm creating a website with Flask as back-end in which I want my JavaScript to query my SQLAlchemy Database to check if there are any users with the same name if yes then display a message if not then continue to the path, Any help will be Appreciated, Thanks

**ALSO I DON'T WANT TO GIVE AWAY ALL MY USERNAMES**

My Flask Code to register username

```
@app.route("/reg/", methods=["POST", "GET"]);
def reg():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["username"]
        
        check = db.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        
        if check is None:
            add = db(username=username)
            udb.session.add(add)
            udb.session.commit()
            
            return render_template("login.html")

        else:
            return ('' ,304) # instead of this I want JavaScript to check and send a message that user already exists   
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

My HTML for Form

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Thank's Again

Comment: What do you mean *"my JavaScript"*? If you mean in the *client*, the code running in your user's browser, then it can't. The point of having the Flask backend is to talk to the database and expose the data via an API (usually following REST principles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript can't do that! but if I understand you in another way so, you can initiate an SQLAlchemy object and pass it to template context something like this:

```
query = Users.query
return render_template('folder/mytemplate.html', user=query)
```

and inside your template you can filter the query as you wish also inside **HTML** `<script>` tags.

```
<script>
    var x = '{{ user.first().name }}' // here you can play with query
<script>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to query if my table name is sup and column name is uname

Comment: The table Users in your case is **sup** and the column `.name` is **.uname**

Answer (score 0):

```
async store(req, res){
    
    const { username } = req.body;

    const userExists = await Dev.findOne({ user: username });

    if(userExists){
        return res.json(userExists);
    }

    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

    const { name, bio, avatar_url: avatar } = response.data;

    const dev = await Dev.create({
        name,
        user: username,
        bio,
        avatar
    });

    return res.json(dev);

}
```

Comment: Some explanation/comments on this code would be a nice addition.